# l2tp проблема с подключением

Tags: l2tp

xl2tpd-1.3.8-2.el7.x86_64

Проблема:

сервер работает, но перестаёт принимать новые соединения.

ip range на сервере 80 адресов.

На момент появления проблемы на сервере 40 - 50 соединений.

Вот такие сообщения на момент подключения клиента в tcpdump'е:

```
IP клиент.l2tp > сервер.l2tp:  l2tp:[TLS](25019/0)Ns=955,Nr=953 *MSGTYPE(ICRQ) *ASSND_SESS_ID(42) *CALL_SER_NUM(45) *BEARER_TYPE()
IP сервер.l2tp > клиент.l2tp:  l2tp:[TLS](7/42)Ns=953,Nr=956 *MSGTYPE(CDN) *RESULT_CODE(2/4 No available IP address) *ASSND_SESS_ID(4059)
IP сервер.l2tp > клиент.l2tp:  l2tp:[TLS](7/0)Ns=954,Nr=956 ZLB
IP клиент.l2tp > сервер.l2tp:  l2tp:[TLS](25019/0)Ns=956,Nr=954 ZLB
```

Помогает перезаруск самого xl2tpd.

Comment: local ip стоит?

Comment: можно ещё прибить ип к логину в chap-secrets. 50 - вроде не много, можно и статикой держать

Comment: local ip стоит, выдача статики не помогает. Позже сделаю выдачу через pppd. Посмотрим.

Answer (score 0):

Такое обычно происходит если ip-range прописан и в xl2tp и в pppd. `xl2tp` выдает адрес при согласовании, а потом `ppp` отдает новый через `lcp`.

Я делаю `assign ip = no` в xl2tpd.conf . Так xl2tp передает ip для согласования в pppd, а сам не ставит.

Но можно наоборот `noip` в опциях (/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd). Так согласование в `ipcp` (`lcp`) будет отключено.

Comment: ip-range только в xl2tpd.conf
если внести noip в options.xl2tpd, то сервер перестаёт выдавать адреса, по крайней мере клиенты вообще не подключаются.

Comment: Может что-то ещё забыл. Пробовал assign IP =no ?

Comment: что-то я запутался. адреса раздаются из пула, который указан в xl2tpd.conf: ip-range.

если добавить assign ip = no в xl2tpd.conf, то по-идее этот параметр должен отключить выдачу адресов из этого пула?
Плюс, повторюсь если добавить опцию noip в options.xl2tp, то пользователи также не могут получить адрес.

Comment: у меня пул в pppd настроен.

Comment: Извиняюсь, а как ip pool через pppd настроить или это через radius  сделано?

Comment: сделал assign = no в xl2tpd, установил всем логинам статику. Проблем больше не наблюдается.